# warning multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

Tags: c++

i have this warning multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

in my code

```
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('ľ')] = 'l';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('š')] = 's';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('č')] = 'c';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('ť')] = 't';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('ž')] = 'z';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('ý')] = 'y';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('á')] = 'a';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('í')] = 'i';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('é')] = 'e';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('ô')] = 'o';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('ú')] = 'u';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('ň')] = 'n';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('ů')] = 'u';
    replacement[static_cast<unsigned char>('ř')] = 'r';
```

Help me please

Comment: Is removing these lines from your source an option? Is disabling the warning an option? Do you understand *why* you get the warning?

Comment: Yes, if i remove this part of code (that replacement lines), it will went without warning. By the way, char replacement[256]; is on top of that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wchar_t at least and put L before you multibyte characters:

```
replacement[L'ľ'] = 'l';
```

Depends on the situation, but will work in most cases.